# Javascript Date out by one day (the day before)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

So I select two dates and build an array based on this.

For example:

```
var getDaysArray = function (s, e) { for (var a = [], d = new Date(s); d <= e; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) { a.push(new Date(d)); } return a; };
var daylist = getDaysArray(new Date(datefrom), new Date(dateto));
```

This returns (daylist) the following:

```
0: Thu Mar 31 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time) {}
1: Fri Apr 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time) {}
2: Sat Apr 02 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time) {}
3: Sun Apr 03 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time) {}
4: Mon Apr 04 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time) {}
5: Tue Apr 05 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time) {}
```

This is correct. However when I then build these dates:

```
const thesedays = daylist.map((v) => v.toISOString().slice(0, 10));
```

This returns (thesedays) the following:

```
0: "2022-03-30"
1: "2022-03-31"
2: "2022-04-01"
3: "2022-04-02"
4: "2022-04-03"
5: "2022-04-04"
```

So it is actually using the day before (March 30 instead of 31 and April 4 instead of 5)

It is the const of thesedays that I need to adjust ... just not sure how?

Comment: `toISOString` === `UTC Date` - so, until 8am in Westralia it'll be the day before

Comment: `new Date(new Date(2022,2,31)-new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60000).toISOString()` will result in `"2022-03-31T00:00:00.000Z"`

Comment: Thanks @Bravo - how do i fix that?

Comment: I just showed you

Comment: `new Date(new Date(value)-new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60000).toISOString() will result in "2022-03-31T00:00:00.000Z"` - where `value` is whatever you're using now - the rest is as is (I'd create a helper function) - there is a simpler way though ... d'oh

Comment: You should add all that as an answer.

Comment: @JoelRoberts - not yet

Comment: Thanks @Bravo - my full code for this part is: const thesedays = daylist.map((v) => v.toISOString().slice(0, 10)); if (saveState == false) {const values = [];for (var i = 0; i < thesedays.length; i++) { values.push({ Date: thesedays[i], From: '', To: '', Distance: '', Stay: '', Notes: '', Document: [] }); } setInputFields(values); } ... so I need to modify the daylist.map line ... just not sure what do adjust to?

Comment: put full code where it can be read, besides, I want to know what `daylist` items are ... Date? String? Number? How is that array constructed? ... so far, if the dates are Date object, I've come up with `daylist.map(v => new Date(Date.parse(new Intl.DateTimeFormat("fr-CA", {year: "numeric", month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit"}).format(v))).toISOString())`

Comment: `"fr-CA"` because french canadians use yyyy-mm-dd as a date format .... those silly Quebecois, everything is back to front

Comment: Thanks again @Bravo - so it is returning the correct dates now but as 0: "2022-03-31T00:00:00.000Z"
1: "2022-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"
2: "2022-04-02T00:00:00.000Z"
3: "2022-04-03T00:00:00.000Z"
4: "2022-04-04T00:00:00.000Z" ... I just need it returned as "2022-04-04" for example

Comment: well ... your `.slice(0,10)` would fix that

Comment: Use https://momentjs.com/  library to make it easier your task

Comment: @SukeshHublikar - why would you even suggest a bloated, legacy project that is in maintenance mode - when the solution is one or two lines of javascript?

Comment: @Bravo if u have issue with momentjs you can use this https://github.com/moment/luxon/

Comment: I have no issue with it, I have an issue with someone suggesting a legacy project for 1 line of code @SukeshHublikar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways ...

```js
const daylist = [
  new Date("2022-01-15T00:00:00"),
  new Date("2022-02-15T00:00:00"),
  new Date("2022-03-15T00:00:00"),
];
const thesedays = daylist.map((v) =>
    `${
        v.getFullYear().toString().padStart(4, "0")
    }-${
        (v.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0")
    }-${
        v.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0")
    }`
);


console.log(thesedays);
```

or

```js
const daylist = [
  new Date("2022-01-15T00:00:00"),
  new Date("2022-02-15T00:00:00"),
  new Date("2022-03-15T00:00:00"),
];
const thesedays = daylist.map(
    (v) =>
        new Date(
            Date.parse(
                new Intl.DateTimeFormat("fr-CA", {
                    year: "numeric",
                    month: "2-digit",
                    day: "2-digit",
                }).format(v)
            )
        ).toISOString().split("T")[0]
);

console.log(thesedays)
```

The first code would be better off with a helper function

```js
const daylist = [
  new Date("2022-01-15T00:00:00"),
  new Date("2022-02-15T00:00:00"),
  new Date("2022-03-15T00:00:00"),
];
const zf = (n, z=2) => n.toString().padStart(z, '0');
const thesedays = daylist.map((v) =>
    `${zf(v.getFullYear(), 4)}-${zf((v.getMonth() + 1))}-${zf(v.getDate())}`
);


console.log(thesedays);
```